# Can I unplug the power from a computer in standby mode?

Tags: windows-xp, shutdown, standby

I shutdown my PC by "standby mode" button instead "poweroff" button at windows xp.
Thus all the coolers are disabled. Then I unplug and plug PC and turn on it. 
(The standby mode is broken)

This method takes much less time than the usual way.
Is it right?

Comment: If you don't care what happens to your data then you could also force everything to close by tweaking your register. http://www.elitezoom.com/how-to-close-program-when-shutdown-windows-xp.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standby mode puts your PC in a very low power state, just enough to keep the RAM and some other components active. When you unplug it, all the data in memory will be **gone**. You don't want to do this if you left some applications open with unsaved data. Standby mode is fine, just remember to always save your work. You don't need to unplug your PC and plug it back in after putting it into standby mode either, simply pressing a key on the keyboard or clicking the mouse should work, unless of course both are USB connected and your motherboard can't recognize them in that power state. If you have a PS/2 keyboard or mouse, pressing or clicking either should bring the machine out of standby.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to disconnect the power, use Hibernation instead of Stand By.

The state of the memory will be written to the hard disk and loaded into memory again when you turn on the computer the next time.

Comment: Hibernation takes more time than Stand By

Comment: I also recommend hibernation, you won't die waiting ten seconds ;-)

Comment: @amouniverso - quite so, but it doesn't "break the standby mode" :) it all comes at a price, if you disconnect the power in standby, you may loose your work if you didn't save it (which also takes time to do :)

Comment: @amouniverso - Why not try just unplugging the computer without doing ANY kind of standby or hibernation, faster still. 
Jesus, use some common sense!

Comment: Is unplug the power from a computer in standby mode and in normal mode bad for it?

Comment: Yes, you should always shut down completely or hibernate before powering off a computer, or else you may suffer data corruption depending on what your programs were doing when you went into standby and unplugged.